# Ubuntu 18.4.2 failsafex running in low graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu, system-recovery

Ubuntu fail safex running in low graphics mode

I changed my theme from unity to gnome from ubuntu login and forgot to change the display manager to gdm3.

And then I restarted low graphics mode.

So I went to Recovery Mode and used all the options.

Root login didnt allow me to Install anything

Dpkg configure successful

Resume normal boot leads to low graphics mode error

Fsck status clean

How can I rid off this problem and get into normal login as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall unity or install tweet manager

Comment: How? Tty also doesn't allow me to login, login loops when I start typing username itself

Answer (score 0):

Started dpkg-reconfigure lightdm in root shell from recovery mode and voila!!!